# How many characters of text would count as sufficient "content" above the fold for mobile?

Tags: google, content, text

It seems that google still refuses to pay for my idea of having the most important part of my mobile web page (the picture) to fill the screen. I guess this is because google believes all the content is "below the fold".

Now I feel that I have to slightly wreck user experience by making the user scroll slightly by adding more textual content on the first screen.

On my desktop site, theres tons of content above the fold, and the picture begins mostly on the second part (after scrolling) and I'm earning money on that.

So my question then is just how many characters of user readable text do I need at minimum for google to think that I have sufficient content above the fold? I don't want users to have to scroll too much to see the picture.

Comment: Oops, read your question wrong... Google is complaining that your ads are too far down the page?

Comment: I never heard that before, I thought "above the fold" means what people see on a page without scrolling.

Comment: I think the main issue is that most of the content above the fold is all picture. People without browsers with the ability to load images have to scroll to see text.

Comment: Do all of those images use unique alt tags? I don't see why Google wouldn't treat them as content.

Comment: The large image on each page does but I marked all images as non-indexable because I don't want google to give others an opportunity to steal them.

Comment: That's most likely your issue right there... Google will only content that is indexable. To be honest if people want to steal, they will... and besides, if people steal your images and then use them on there site, then it can actually increases your image authority and can gain traffic from it... because just like text, Google can detect image duplicates... You can test this by dragging a image from your computer into Google images, it'll scan for similar images... people using your images, isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Also, you can use it to your advantage by using a creative commons attribute license which will actually increase your rankings.

Comment: I already do have terms and conditions set out for the images and those terms are accessible as a link on every page. I don't want to write out the full terms on every page or google would see that as duplicate content.

Comment: Mike, I know I say this a lot, but you worry far to much. Google and other search engines are not stupid, they understand repeatable content and in no shape or form will it hurt your rankings... take Pro Webmasters as a prime example, it has 100,000's of pages with `Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook. Your Answer By posting your answer, you agree to the privacy policy and terms of service.` at the bottom of almost every page, its not duplicate content, its repeated content that is ignored by Google in the ranking of the page kw'

Comment: With creative commons there would be at less text, just `This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.` and with the logo if you choose, which I do because it actually makes the page look nice. Don't get confused with repeatable content with duplicate pages, duplicate pages are like for like copies, just 'duplicate content' is normally associated with a 3rd party site... when they like-for-like copy your content (but when this occurs, they get punished, not you)... Google records the source/discovered.

Comment: @Mike if you need to show your image on top of the text, try to place the text above the image in the code of the page and with CSS visually make the image be above text